# What are the branches of mathematics?

Tags: big-list

What are all the branches of mathematics? I want to know this so that I can compare between them, so if you can give me with them a brief look of what they are about that would be awesome.

Comment: In the link of the comment from @amWhy you'll find an answer with the link to the American Mathematical Societies Mathematics Subject Classification....

Comment: Okay thanks for that